Would this logic be considered constructive?
I have asked about similar logics before, but this one is different.
The logics that I’ve asked about in the past take the Gödel-McKinsey-Tarski translation for Intuitionistic Propositional Logic to classical $S4$, but change the translation of negation to
$t(\neg A)=\neg \Box t(A)$.
If you define the translation thus:
$t(p)=\Box p$
$t(\neg A)=\neg \Box t(A)$
$t(A \to B)=\Box (t(A) \to t(B))$
$t(A \leftrightarrow B)=\Box (t(A) \leftrightarrow t(B))$,
it holds that one can define the rest of the Intuitionsitic operators that respect their BHK definitions. For example,
$\bot:=\neg (p \to p)$
$\top:=(\bot \to \bot)$
$(A \land B):=(A \leftrightarrow (A \to B))$
$(A \lor B):=(\neg A \to (\neg B \to B))$ etc.
The negation is still non-constructive; any axiomatization for it needs at least one non-constructive axiom. However, the definable disjunction has the disjunction property, re Gödel’s results about $S4$. Is the following axiomatization understandable as constructive?
Lowercase letters are propositional atoms, and uppercase letters are arbitrary formulas.
$p \to (A \to p)$
$(A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C))$
$\neg (A \to A) \to B$
$((A \to B) \to C) \to (\neg C \to \neg B)$
$(\neg (A \to B) \to B) \to (A \to B)$
$(A \leftrightarrow B) \to (A \to B)$
$(A \leftrightarrow B) \to (B \to A)$
$(A \to B) \to ((B \to A) \to (A \leftrightarrow B))$
From $\vdash A$ and $\vdash A \to B$, infer $B$.
From $\vdash A(p)$, infer $\vdash A(B \to C)$, where $B \to C$ is uniformly substituted for $p$ in $A$.
P.S., I ask because I wonder whether this logic would be suitable for constructive mathematical theories, given similar definitions for $\exists$ and $\forall$ so that they would satisfy the BHK interpretation. In such a case, formulas like $A \to \exists x A$ would be invalid for arbitrary formulas, but would hold for quantified formulas and unquantified positive literals like $x \in y$. Thanks.

$(\neg (A \to B) \to B) \to (A \to B)$ for true $A$ looks like consequentia mirabilis, so I'd start by, investigating if malicious consequences of that prevail in your system.

@Nikolaj-K yes, and the standard consequentia mirabilis is provable in this system. However, since $\neg A \to (B \to \neg A)$ is invalid, the semi-classical results are strongly mitigated.
